# Making an Oracle Apex column read-only

Tags: oracle

Read-only attribute not working fine in interactive grid.
when salary equal `3000` the `department` column attribute  must be read-only, it's working fine but when changing the salary the `column` still read-only how I can change this attribute when the salary value change

Comment: did u tried refreshing the page after you change the salary  and did u see in the database that it has been changed ?

Comment: no before that , i can do this only when value change . thanks.

Comment: Are you doing this with javascript?

Comment: no only ,i was change the attribute when the  salary column equal 3000 and the execute attribute to  ( for each row)